# Is there any way to simplify a variable expression or solve for a variable in terms of variable in Latex?

Tags: variable

It would mean so much if someone could help me with this. I am doing some research and am using models and for my math analysis, I have to solve for C using this simplified version of my model. Is there anywhere I could input this and without having to change from latex, have it solve for C?

```
\lambda_c C \left(1-\frac{C+\gamma(P+Q)}{K}\right)-\alpha C + \nu P =  \lambda_p C \left(1-\frac{C+\gamma(P+Q)}{K}\right)+\alpha C
```

If this isn't possible, is there a way I could input the individual expressions such as squaring an expression as seen below and having a simplifier distribute it for me w/ out changing from latex?

```
((\lambda_c-\lambda_p)  -K\lambda_c  + (\lambda_c -\lambda_p)( \gamma (P+Q)) + K\lambda_p +2K\alpha)^2
```

Comment: This is not a question about LaTeX itself so would not be on-topic here, but I think Mathematica and sympy has ways to import from/export to LaTeX format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE!

Comment: The relatively new `luacas` package provides a rudimentary computer algebra system for LuaLaTeX. I have not tried it so cannot comment further on the extent to which it meets your needs.

Comment: Since there is a package that provides computer algebra functionality as a (Lua)LaTeX package it seems the question is indeed entirely on topic.